# Drag and Drop reordering NOT working in Windows Phone App XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to visualize a ListView reorderable by the user throw interaction.

I was able to achieve it in a local machine app, but whith the same code in a Windows Phone 8.1 App, it does not work. The list shows but is not draggable nor reorderable.

Here is my code:

```
<Page
x:Class="App21.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App21"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              Width="392" 
              Height="352" 
              CanReorderItems="True" 
              AllowDrop="True" 
              Margin="120,0,0,0" >
        <ListViewItem Content="Item 1" FontSize="40" Margin="0" />
        <ListViewItem Content="Item 2" FontSize="38" Padding="2,0"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Item 3" FontSize="36" Padding="4,0"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Item 4" FontSize="34" Padding="6,0"/>

    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Does anyone have any suggestion about what would possibly be the reason it is not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried **tapping and holding** the ListViewItem, and then dragging it?

Comment: Did you set ListViewReorderMode of listview code behind?

Comment: Yes! That was the answer, but I think there's not much documentation about it! And I think it's weird that the properties CanReorderItems, AllowDrop and CanDragItems do not work in WP8.1.